# Power BI deployed in AWS & GCP?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, deployment, powerbi

Can Power BI be deployed on Google Cloud Platform(GCP) and Amazon Web Services(AWS)?

Comment: StackOverflow is a site for programming Q&A. You'll probably receive a better response to this type of question at https://www.reddit.com/r/aws and https://www.reddit.com/r/googlecloud/.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can connect to GCP and AWS data sources, but the Power BI Service is a O365/Azure service only.

You can install Power BI Desktop on windows VMs in GCP and AWS, but published reports will go to the Power BI Service. You also have the option of deploying Power BI Report Server on VMs in GCP or AWS